# Android singleton between service and actions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-activity

I am working on a project that. It will connect to a remote host using tcp sockets from a service. And interact with it for getting and sending data.

The flow, I have planned is;

a singleton socket class. Which returns a **connected** socket refference;

an activity to ask user for remote server's ip and port.
a service triggered(**intent**) by the activity with the parameters of ip:port.
service will get the socket using singleton socket class.
and then service will read a data; parse it and show user for user actions in a new action window ( **intended**).
after user completed the action; result will be sent to the server. and new request will be read.

problem/query is here;

- when you come back to the service for second data read operation; will the socket be there ? (or garbage collected )
  because after data read operation started no new connection accepted.
- will the first service die after calling the user actions activity ?
- what happens if I call the service using startService from an activity, a new service created or the existing  before started service called back again ?
- how can I let the service live for ever unless I said it to die.

Sorry, If I am asking silly questions.

Comment: Why do you want to use a service? Have you considered using an AsyncTask instead?

Comment: sadly, this is my assignment project and I have to use services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I see it:

> when you come back to the service for second data read operation; will
>   the socket be there ? (or garbage collected ) because after data read
>   operation started no new connection accepted.

If the object is static and has the socket as a member variable it will most likely be there, you should have safeguards in your single pattern to shield from this problem `(if single==null){...}`, you could also try managing it by overriding the `Application` class and adding a factory method in there. You need to make sure the socket is open and closed correctly and not just left hanging as this could create problems

EDIT:

Whether the actual socket is still open will depend on the timeout of the socket

> will the first service die after calling the user actions activity ?

Services need to be told to stop and so it will not die

> what happens if I call the service using startService from an
>   activity, a new service created or the existing before started service
>   called back again ?

If the service is running, the it will not create another, it will call the `onStartCommand()` of the running service

> how can I let the service live for ever unless I said it to die.

This is default behavior

Comment: I am already using the null check singleton usage that you suggest. And my mistake to not to read the service page from developers page.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html Section : **Service Lifecycle**

thanks, I will try and set the answer sooner !!

Comment: No problem, still a reasonable question, if the answer is correct please mark it as such.